# Unable to save the data in model from firestore after migrating to null safety

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, dart-null-safety

So, I have a user model where i want to store the value from the document present in firestore and for that i have the following code:-

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

class UserModel
{
  final String? id;
  final String? username;
  final String? email;
  final String? url;
  final String? androidNotificationToken;

  UserModel({
    this.id,
    this.username,
    this.email,
    this.url,
    this.androidNotificationToken,
  });

  factory UserModel.fromDocument(DocumentSnapshot doc)
  {
    return UserModel(
      id: doc.data()['id'], //error
      username: doc.data()['username'],//error
      email: doc.data()['email'],//error
      url: doc.data()['url'],//error
      androidNotificationToken: doc.data()['androidNotificationToken'],//error
    );
  }
}
```

And the error am facing is that a red line is showing error on the square brackets after doc.data() as marked in my code.
The error is:-

```
The method '[]' can't be unconditionally invoked because the receiver can be 'null'.
```

The one fix which i found was to replace doc.data()['id'] with (doc.data() as dynamic)['id]. So is it the best approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should replace:

```
doc.data() as dynamic['id']
```

with:

```
doc.data() as Map<String, dynamic>['id']
```

[DocumentSnapshot.data](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase/latest/firebase_firestore/DocumentSnapshot/data.html) is of type `Map<String, dynamic>`.

Check out the [migration guide](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/2.0.0_migration/#migration) for `cloud_firestore 2.0.0`.